# Razor syntax, the code is not executed in AjaxOptions OnComplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have such MVC code and would like to pass Model value `@conversionModel.SourceFileName` Unfortunately this code is not actually executed, what correct Razor syntax would be in my case?

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Remove file", "RemoveFile", "Converter", 
    new { id = @conversionModel.ProcessId }, 
    new AjaxOptions { 
    OnComplete = "RemoveFile(@conversionModel.SourceFileName);" 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Remove file", 
    "RemoveFile", 
    "Converter", 
    new { 
        id = conversionModel.ProcessId 
    }, 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        OnComplete = string.Format(
            "RemoveFile({0})", 
            Json.Encode(conversionModel.SourceFileName)
        ) 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The string you pass to "OnComplete" is not parsed by the Razor engine, it's just a plain string of javascript executed when the ajax call is completed.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Remove file", "RemoveFile", "Converter", 
    new { id = @conversionModel.ProcessId }, 
    new AjaxOptions { 
       OnComplete = string.Format("RemoveFile({0})", Json.Encode(conversionModel.SourceFileName))
    })
```

Update: instead of just quoting the string it should be encoded using Json.Encode as Darin notes.

Comment: -1, what if the path contains the \ character which is quite possible for a path? This will break the javascript. The only reliable way to pass strings to a javascript function is to actually JSON encode them.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks for downvoting my solution because it doesn't cover any possibility *not* mentioned in the OP's question. Whether or not to encode the string has never been asked here. It *is* noteworthy (and I've updated my answer accordingly). But actually *downvoting* my solution, which solves the OP's initial problem is rather questionable.

Comment: the OP's original problem was the fact that the `RemoveFile` javascript was never executed. It was never executed because he didn't properly encode the string passed as argument and he got a javascript error. With your initial solution, it was the same: the parameter was not properly encoded. Now that you have fixed your answer I remove my downvote, except that now your answer looks the same as mine.

Comment: The cause of the issue was not that the string was not encoded, but that he uses Razor syntax within the string assigned to OnComplete. The rendered link would get an attribute like `data-ajax-complete="RemoveFile(@conversionModel.SourceFileName);"`, because `@conversionModel.SourceFileName` isn't expanded inside the string. The JS interpreter has probably bailed out when it reached the '@' sign. With my initial solution the attribute looks like `data-ajax-complete="RemoveFile(&#39;foobar&#39;)"`, assuming conversionModel.SourceFileName is "foobar". This would at least have run.